# How to echo referral post custom field (ACF) value with help of Referer HTTP in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, http-referer

[Advance custum field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW7cI.jpg)
[Ultrasurf Portable](https://glow786.com/ultrasurf-vpn-for-pc-download/)

When i click download button on https://pkhorse.com/ it goes to  i need to echo refferal post custum field value into second page..
Thiscode is working for title https://pkhorse.com/inpage-urdu-2009/

```
 `<?php
    $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $back_id = url_to_postid($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if( $back_id > 0 ){
         $back_title = get_the_title( $back_id );
         echo "<a href='{$url}'>Go back to the {$back_title}</a>"; 
    }
?>
I want something from referral page 
<?php the_field('url'); ?> `
```

Comment: Pass the referral page ID as a second parameter to retrieve information from that page as described in the [ACF resources](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/). `<?php the_field('url', $back_id); ?>`

Comment: Thanks it working, i have no words to say Thanks to you Sir.